# Why do I get the 'match case unused' warning with a type annotation but not without?

Tags: ocaml

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967427/match-case-unused-in-ocaml) about this warning, but the answers don't make sense in my circumstances.

I have this bit of code:

```ml
let someFun (arg: string) : unit Lwt.t =
  try%lwt
    do_something arg in
    Lwt.return ()
  with (error: exn) ->
    Format.printf "Error with '%s': %s" arg (Printexc.to_string error);
    Lwt.return ()
```

I get this error:

> Warning 11: this match case is unused.

If I remove the `exn` type annotation on `error`, my code compiles without warnings. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is merely an imperfection in lwt's ppx which fails to detect `(error:exn)` as a catch-all case. To understand the issue with the annotation, you would need to know that the `try...with` case is translated to:

```
function
| (error : exn) ->
     Format.printf "Error with '%s': %s" arg (Printexc.to_string error);
     Lwt.return ()
| exn -> Lwt.fail exn
```

Here, the second case is redundant and was added by the ppx itself. Without the type annotation, `lwt_ppx` is clever enough to detect that this case is not necessary and thus only generates:

```
       function
        | error ->
          Format.printf "Error with '%s': %s" arg (Printexc.to_string error);
          Lwt.return ()
```

EDIT: This issue should be fixed in the next version of `ppx_lwt`: [ppx: recognize constrained catch-all cases #640](https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt/pull/640)

Comment: I remember writing that code, it was definitely an heuristic! I would appreciate a bug report for that. :)

Comment: The ppx code was nice, so I directly sent a PR fixing the issue.

Comment: That explains also why the error didn't point to a line in my code. Thank you for the explanation and the fix.